# Select MultiIndex rows by level, in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

How can I select rows from a MultiIndex DataFrame that have more than 1 level? For example, given the following DataFrame:

```
           col
L1  L2     
a   1      5624
    2      1656
    3      265677
    4      3755
b   5      47
    6      85544
c   7      97656
d   8      12774
e   9      111
    10     9478
```

I would like to end up with a DataFrame that looks like:

```
         col
L1  L2     
a   1      5624
    2      1656
    3      265677
    4      3755
b   5      47
    6      85544
e   9      111
    10     9478
```

Comment: What's the criteria used for selection? It's ambiguous from the example

Comment: The criteria is that I want rows that have multiple values within L1. "c" and "d" both only have a single corresponding L2 sub-index, so I don't want to select them.

Answer (score 1):

Check `transform` `count`

```
out = df[df.groupby(level=0)['col'].transform('count').values>1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to consider the first level:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values('L1').duplicated(keep=False)]
# or
df[df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep=False)]
```

If you want to consider all levels:

```
df[df.index.to_frame().apply(pd.Series.duplicated, keep=False).any(1)]
```

output:

```
          col
L1 L2        
a  1     5624
   2     1656
   3   265677
   4     3755
b  5       47
   6    85544
e  9      111
   10    9478
```